# Capacitance detection circuit in LTspice

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, sensor, filter, rectifier

I have designed a circuit to detect ice in software LTSpice. When I did ac analysis, it shows the gain is constant from 10KHZ to 10MHZ. That means, I can detect ice during operationg the sensor with these frequencies range. However, ice can be only detected at low frequencies. i.e 1Khz. So I want to make my circuit to works from 500Hz to 10MHZ. So I need ac response as flat with same circuit by making small changes. Please find the photographs and help me how to do it?[image]

Comment: How does the above circuit detect ice? On what physical principle does it work?

Comment: This circuit **is not going to work in the real world** as there is **no DC feedback** meaning that the output of the opamp will clip to its maximum or minimum voltage depending on the opamp's input offset. If you don't understand what this means I suggest that you study the free Ebook: Opamps for everyone: https://web.mit.edu/6.101/www/reference/op_amps_everyone.pdf

Comment: Oh, and don't say *"but it is OK in the simulator, only 2.46 mV at the output"* because in the simulator the opamp will not have any DC offset until you enable that and do a Monte Carlo simulation.

Comment: I do not understand what do you mean by DC offset. It has already worked for high frequencies and I want to implement it for low frequencies. What concept should I read in order to know this? in the same book?

Comment: Why is your title about "capacitance detection", yet the question says "ice detection"?

Comment: Bimpelrekkie. As you told, the circuit is not giving the ltspice values. When I simulated on breadbaord, I am getting DC offset output as 12V with VCC = 15V. But when I decrease the VCC, the offset is decreasing. Can you help me how to remove this offset?